# how to ignore certificate error on qml WebEngineView

Tags: qt, qml, qtwebengine

what is correct way to ignore certificate errors in qml webEngineView? this one didnt work for me! qt documentation is so bad about web engine view here is certificate page : [certificate error](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtwebengine-webenginecertificateerror.html#ignoreCertificateError-method)

```
WebEngineView {
        id:webView
        certificateError: WebEngineCertificateError.ignoreCertificateError()
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to do it when the WebEngineView notifies through the signal [certificateError](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtwebengine-webengineview.html#certificateError-signal):

```
WebEngineView {
    id:webView
    onCertificateError: error.ignoreCertificateError()
}
```